# How to subtract two row's date within same column using a SQL query showing days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two dates in the same column and I need subtract the days/hours between them.
`SELECT [ID],[DATA] FROM [DADOS]`

I want to show like:

`ID Date         DiffDate
 1  2017-05-12   0
 2  2017-05-14   2
 3  2017-05-28   14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using SQL Server 2008, you'll need to use a `LEFT JOIN` onto the same table:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT ID,
           CONVERT(date, [date]) AS [date] --That's not confusing
    FROM (VALUES(1,'20170512'),
                (2,'20170514'),
                (3,'20170528')) V(ID, [date]))
SELECT V1.ID,
       V1.[date],
       ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY,V2.[date],V1.[date]),0) AS DiffDate
FROM VTE V1
     LEFT JOIN VTE V2 ON V1.ID -1 = V2.ID;
```

If, however, you have SQL Server 2012+, then you can achieve this much more easily  using `LAG`, meaning you don't need to scan the table twice:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT ID,
           CONVERT(date, [date]) AS [date] --That's not confusing
    FROM (VALUES(1,'20170512'),
                (2,'20170514'),
                (3,'20170528')) V(ID, [date]))
SELECT V.ID,
       V.[date],
       ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(V.[date]) OVER (ORDER BY V.ID),V.[date]),0) AS DiffDate
FROM VTE V;
```

Answer (score 0):

For older version of SQL server
you should use a query like below

```
 SELECT 
    d1.[ID],
    d1.[DATA], 
    DiffDate=DATEDIFF(d,ISNULL(d2.[Data],d1.[Data]),d1.[Data]) 
    FROM [DADOS] d1
     LEFT JOIN [DADOS] d2
     ON d1.[id]=d2.[id]+1
```

You can **[LEAD/LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** functions if your SQL server version supports them like below

```
SELECT 
[ID],
[DATA], 
DiffDate=DATEDIFF(d,ISNULL(LAG([Data]) over( order by [Id]),[Data]),[Data]) 
FROM [DADOS]
```

Note that ISNULL is to take care of first row's 0 value

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't support `LAG()`, which is what you really need.  I would recommend using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT d.*,
       COALESCE(DATEDIFF(day, dprev.DATA, d.DATA), 0)
FROM DADOS d OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) d2.*
      FROM DADOS d2
      WHERE d2.DATA < d.DATA
      ORDER BY DATA DESC
     ) dprev;
```